# Двойной z-index в одном DIV

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть такой код:

```
<div class="inner">
   <div class="title">
      <h1>Тема такая-то</h1>
   </div>
 <p>Описание такое-то</p>
</div>

<div class="menu">
Пункты меню
</div>
```

Необходимо, чтобы слои шли в следующем порядке: на заднем плане `inner`, затем `menu` и сверху `title`. Если `title` присвоить z-index выше, чем у `menu`, то и `inner` тоже вылезает над меню, так как это его родитель. Дело в том, что класс `inner` выводится на экран плагином за раз и отдельно вынести `title` из него не получится. А нужно, чтобы он был над меню. Вот, для наглядности.

[image]
 unarque и For suggestions принадлежать одному DIV, который выводится целиком одним плагином. Сейчас у этого DIV z-index выше, чем у меню. Все супер, но при раскрытии меню, оно проваливается под текст For suggedtions. Как быть?

Comment: а title вынести за пределы inner не вариант?

Comment: У меня плагин выводит на экран класс целиком и за раз. Title не вынести за пределы этого класса, т.к. он уже не будет обрабатываться плагином.

Comment: а при клику на menu присваивать дополнительный класс с z-index выше чем inner а пры закрытии уберать даный клас

Answer (score 1):

Смотря какой css:

```css
.inner {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}

.menu {
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  height: 60px;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  z-index: 3;
  top:10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
     <div class="title">
        <h1>Тема такая-то</h1>
     </div>
   <p>Описание такое-то</p>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
  Пункты меню
  </div>
</div>
```

С `fixed`, тоже можно.

Comment: Видите, пункты меню под тему проваливаются. В этом и проблема. Если дочернему классу присвоить z-index выше родительского, то и родительский повышается до него.